# How to solve TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the image of error i am encountering here

[image]

All the codes can be found here: https://github.com/callmebhawesh/react/
I thought it's better to provide github link so that you can run and see instead of writing everything here.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Todos line in your App.js

```
<Todos todo={todos} />
```

To this one

```
<Todos todos={todos} />
```

Basically you're trying to access todos[0] but you're passing a prop called todo not todos, so when doing todos[0] is trying to access an undefined prop that does not exist.

Comment: src/MyComponents/Todos.js
  Line 8:30:  'todos' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: I got this error

Comment: Where is that, in your github that line is like this: <TodoItem todo={props.todos[0]}/> so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you're destructuring the wrong item.  In your `<Todos />` component, you're passing in the first Todo item in the list.  Each todo has the following properties:

- sno
- title
- desc

In your `<Todo />` component, you're trying to extract out a "todo" property, and that doesn't exist in your object.  To get your title, you'd destructure out the title from your Todo object.

```
const Todo = ({title}) => {
    // Render here
}
```

You can extract the other properties as needed.